# Copy date from Excel paste to Word in different format

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a macro that copies certain data from Excel and pastes them into Word, however i'm looking for a way to modify the date format before pasting.

This currently copies the date as it appears in Excel, i.e. 16/01/2015

```
Sub NoFormatPaste()
    wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
    wdFind.Forward = True
    wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    wdFind.Execute
    appWd.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
    CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 14).Select
Selection.Copy
wdFind.Text = "DATE"
Call NoFormatPaste
```

However I would like to paste it in a different format. Something like this, but its not working. i.e. Friday 16th January 2015

```
Sub NoFormatDatePaste()
    wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
    wdFind.Forward = True
    wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
    wdFind.Execute
    appWd.Selection = Format(date_example, "dddd d mmmm yyyy")
    CutCopyMode = False
End Sub

wdFind.Text = "DATE"
Call NoFormatDatePaste
```

I can paste the entire code if needed, these are just the bits that aren't working.

It seems you can't just tell Word what values to print, and the values need actually copying and pasting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your date value in a string and pass it to the other procedure:

```
Dim dateValue as String

dateValue = Cells(Application.ActiveCell.Row, 14).Value

wdFind.Text = "DATE"

Call NoFormatPaste(dateValue)
```

In the other procedure, don't use the `.Paste` method, instead you can just insert the string.

```
Sub NoFormatDatePaste(dateValue as String)

wdFind.Replacement.Text = ""
wdFind.Forward = True
wdFind.Wrap = wdFindContinue
wdFind.Execute
appWd.Selection.InsertAfter Format(dateValue, "dddd d mmmm yyyy")


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however is there a function instead of InsertAfter so the new value overrides the selection, instead of inserting it after it?

Comment: Its ok I added `appWd.Selection.Delete` before the last line so it removes the found text before inserting the date.

Comment: Maybe try `.Replace` instead of `.InsertAfter`

Comment: Tried `.Replace` and it didnt like it, deleting the text and inserting the date is working just fine for now, thank you for your help.

Comment: Cool, if it's working for you then that's all that matters :) But I know there's another method that would do it directly without the deletion. (Word is not my specialty so I don't know it off the top of my head, though)